# Running Flutter with XCode, normal build works, archived version builds but doesn't display properly

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, xcode-archive

I am working on an app using Flutter.  When I run the program normally on iPhone using either Flutter or XCode, the program functions normally and will display my widgets.  However, when I archive the build using XCode and upload it, when I try the archived version using TestFlight, I am seeing just a gray box where my normal widgets were supposed to be.  Has anyone experienced this?

[image: gray boxes instead of tile with text and widgets]

[image: big gray box instead of buttons and widgets]

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app as a release build the problem should appear
use this command `flutter run --release`

Comment: ok thanks, let me try

Comment: if the solution worked, please verify my answer., thanks.